# Build errors with downloaded repo and CocoaPods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am very new to Xcode, and using Swift, as well as CocoaPods. I have downloaded someone else's code which used CocoaPods libraries to continue developing the software and I have installed CocoaPods using home-brew onto my computer, and also in the target folder.
I have used the Podfile which was originally provided to me by the original developer and I have run `pod install` on the folder.

When I open Xcode to build the project, I receive the errors pointing to files that don't exist which are related to debug files. If I point the build towards 'none' for the debug files then I get the message that the sandbox is not in sync. I try to reinstall and re run `pod install` with no success.

Is there someone willing to screen share with me at some point and help me through this?

Pod File contents:

```
platform :ios, '13.2'

target 'ATASafety' do
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'OAuthSwift', '~> 2.0.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end
```

Errors when building

> .../ataa_safety_app-master/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ATASafety/Pods-ATASafety.debug.xcconfig:1:1: unable to open file (in target "ATASafety" in project "ATASafety")

When I open the target support file, it is empty...
was something supposed to autocreate there when I ran `pod install`??

Comment: are you opening the .xcworkspace instead of the .xcodeproj?

Comment: No, I'm running the .xcodeproj file. I also get the error error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation... but I've run pod install on the folder.

Comment: If you’re using cocoa pods, you should be opening the xcworkspace

Comment: I get the same error running the .xcworkspace

Comment: hmm. try running `pod repo update` in your terminal, open up the project and do cmd+shift+k before running the project.